# how do I rewrite any uri not beginning with a directory to that directory?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to set up a rewrite rule so any request is forwarded to a specific uri unless the request begins with that uri.

For example, http://myhost/anything should redirect to http://myhost/mydirectory
But http://myhost/mydirectory/mysubdirectory/myfile should not be touched (i.e it should return http://myhost/mydirectory/mysubdirectory/myfile)

I've tried various things, google and stack overflow searches with no success...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydirectory/
RewriteRule .* /mydirectory/ [R]
```

Help appreciated :)

Updated: As per comments below I have fixed this. I actually have two methods of rewriting the rules and both appear to work. I don't know if one or the other is a preferred method though.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydirectory/
RewriteRule .* /mydirectory/ [R]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/mydirectory/.* - [L]
RewriteRule .* /mydirectory/ [R]
```

Comment: Existing rule should work already. In any case -- try this: `RewriteRule ^(?!mydirectory).* /mydirectory/ [R]`. That's if rule is placed in .htaccess file, if in server config -- it needs to be altered a bit

Comment: What do you see in the mod_rewrite log?

Comment: Lazyone - The existing rule works except it also rewrites http://myhost/mydirectory/mysubdirectory/myfile, which obviously I don't want it to do. Re your suggestion. it is going in server config in a virtualhost block. How do I need to alter it? I'll also do some more checking of logs, etc...

Comment: Ok, so it works. My problem was a ScriptAliasMatch that was matching on the "/mydirectory/" so anything beginning with that was firing the script. I changed that to "^/mydirectory/$" and it works now.

Comment: Both look just fine. I myself prefer the second one, because it is easier to remember/type. Also if you have multiple rules you would have to repeat the RewriteCond.